When i run npm run android on my vs code i got this error... what can i do
info Installing the app...
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
9 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 5 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A build operation failed.
      Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\piyus\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\716f968cc1e5225035406d1e56ec874f-06068847-f68e-4407-947b-c375036a555c) to immutable location (C:\Users\piyus\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\716f968cc1e5225035406d1e56ec874f)
   > Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\piyus\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\716f968cc1e5225035406d1e56ec874f-06068847-f68e-4407-947b-c375036a555c) to immutable location (C:\Users\piyus\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\716f968cc1e5225035406d1e56ec874f)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1m 35s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. > A build operation failed. Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\piyus\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\716f968cc1e5225035406d1e56ec874f-06068847-f68e-4407-947b-c375036a555c) to immutable location (C:\Users\piyus\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\716f968cc1e5225035406d1e56ec874f) > Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\piyus\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\716f968cc1e5225035406d1e56ec874f-06068847-f68e-4407-947b-c375036a555c) to immutable location (C:\Users\piyus\.gradle\caches\transforms-4\716f968cc1e5225035406d1e56ec874f) * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 1m 35s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I tried many things but nothing happened.

I had the same problem too. What worked for me was deleting the C:\Users\{YOUR_USERNAME}\.gradle\ folder and then building the project again.
